# Error obtaining logarithms of base 2 in c

Tags: c, math

I want to obtain the binary logarithms of the numbers 1 to 2048, but I don´t know why it doesn´t work, it doesn´t obtain the right numbers.

If I use floats, it works, but it used to work with integers, i have already done a program with this method and now it doesn´t work because of that. Changing the unsigned int to int doesn´t work. Someone knows why?

```
for(unsigned int numero=1;numero<=2048;numero*=2)
{
    int x=log10(numero)/log10(2);
    printf("%d\n",x);
}

return 0;
```

It prints:

```
0 1 2 2 4 5 5 6 8 9 10 11
```

It should be:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Looks like it works for some numbers, but i don´t understand why it doesn´t work for all numbers.

Comment: You don't have [log2()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log2) available?

Answer (score 2):

`log10` returns a floating point number (double). The value of `log10` is not exactly representible in floating point for most numbers you pass, therefore you might get something like `log10(8)/log10(2) == 2.9999999` instead of an exact `3`. The conversion to `int` truncates it down to `2`. To fix that you should round properly:

```
int x = lrint(log10(numero)/log10(2));
```

Or in case your compiler doesn't have the `lrint` function you can use:

```
int x = log10(numero)/log10(2) + 0.5;
```

which would work for this case.

Notice that there are alternative ways to calculate the desired result. Since floating-point numbers already store the exponent in base 2, you can retrieve it with a call to `frexp`:

```
int x;
frexp(numero, &x);
```

Another way would be to avoid floating point math altogether and use an intrinsic to get the index of the last bit set in `numero`. Unfortunately there's no cross-platform way to do that.

Comment: I don't think that second one is valid C syntax.

Comment: Finding the first set bit of an int:  You might be pleasantly surprised that the naive solution gets optimised to one instruction with either modern clang or GCC builds.

Comment: @Shawn: apologies, didn't notice the [c] tag.